# How to build with swipl on sublime

Tags: prolog, sublimetext, sublimetext3, swi-prolog, sublime-build

I'm trying to compile prolog's code on sublime text 3 but I always get

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'swipl'
[cmd: ['swipl', '-f', '', '-t', 'main', '--quiet']]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

because I don't know how to modify the path to swipl on sublime. Some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to create a new build system for Prolog. First, I assume that you already have `swipl` installed and it is on your `$PATH`. Open Terminal and run the command

```
which swipl
```

to find you where it is located, then copy the full path. For example, it may return `/usr/local/bin/swipl`. Then, in Sublime, create a new JSON file with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/swipl", "-f", "$file_name", "-t", "main", "--quiet"],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^Warning: (.+):([0-9]+)",
    "selector": "source.prolog"
}
```

substituting `"/usr/local/bin/swipl"` for the actual path you copied earlier. Save this in your `Packages/User` directory (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`) as `Prolog_swipl.sublime-build`.

Then, go to `Tools -> Build System` and select `Prolog_swipl`. You should now be able to build your code using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Make sure that your file is saved before building.

Comment: You need to define a main/0 function for AutoBuild to work. See the README for that package https://github.com/alnkpa/sublimeprolog/blob/master/README.md. `main :- your_foo(X,variables). write("formatting commands",[X]).`

Answer (score 2):

Installing prolog from brew will help

```
brew install swi-prolog
```

After installing, restart sublime text, and it should build.